# Javascript Regular Expression for CSS

Tags: javascript, css, regex, parsing

I'm trying to extract a value through Javascript from an element's CSS3 attribute such as the following:

**CSS:**

```
el {
  -moz-transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 27px, 0px);
}
```

**Javascript (jQuery)**

```
var style = $('el').css('-moz-transform');
```

The *style* variable takes the following string when the script runs: **"matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 27px, 0px)"**

I'd like to extract the number corresponding to the **27px** field inside that string.

I imagine the fastest, or at least most elegant way to do so is with regular expressions, although I don't really know how to use them in JS.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('el').css('-moz-transform').split(',')[4]
```

Please, Test the below [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/umeshpatil86/xBHPr/2/) in Mozilla firefox `-moz-transform`  is used only in Firefox.

Comment: The force is strong with this one.

Comment: Thanks. Don't know how I didn't think about that before .

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
var value = style.split(',')[4];
```

If you want to remove the spaces:

```
var value = style.split(/, */)[4];
```

Comment: What about the spaces between the commas? Well, I suppose if you use `parseInt`, the spaces won't matter.

Answer (score 0):

IMO the easiest way to do this is actually just splitting the string on comma's and getting the 5th parameter, no need to fire up the regex engine

```
var val = style.split(',')[4];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just do a split on the commas.

```
var style = $('el').css('-moz-transform').split(",")[4];
```